# TestContext always Null

Tags: citrus-framework

Is there any way I can inject TestContext in my cucumber step class?

I am using citrus, spring, and cucumber together with the latest version. But when I use the below injection I always get null pointer exception of the TestContext. For TestDesigner and TestRunner I have no issue to get.

```
@CitrusResource private TestContext         tContext;
```

and in the log i am seeing

```
Failed to get proper TestContext from Cucumber Spring application context: No qualifying bean of type 'com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext' available
```

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously using the setting

```
cucumber.api.java.ObjectFactory=cucumber.runtime.java.spring.CitrusSpringObjectFactory
```

in the `cucumber.properties`.

When doing so you need to manually add the Citrus Spring configuration with `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on your steps class.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CitrusSpringConfig.class)
public class MySteps {

    @CitrusResource
    private TestDesigner designer;

    [...]

}
```

In case you are using the default `cucumber.xml` Spring XML application context you need to add the Citrus Spring config as bean to that file:

```
<!-- JavaConfig bean post-processor -->
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor"/>

<!-- Citrus Java config -->
<bean id="citrusSpringConfig" class="com.consol.citrus.config.CitrusSpringConfig"/>
```

Comment: I  added the CitrusSpringConfig.class and no more Failed to get proper TestContext from Cucumber Spring application context: No qualifying bean of type 'com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext' available appear. But still, the @CitrusResource private TestContext         tContext;
 still null pointer. I am using citurs 2.7.7 and cucumber 3.0.2 anyway. My question is can we inject the TextContext in my class? since TextDesigner and TextRunner is able to inject